# Azcopy empty folders

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2, azcopy

I need to sync data from a local server to an Azure Cloud v2 storage account.
I’m using the command
azcopy sync “source server” “storage container “ —-delete-destination=true
but the issue I’m facing is that empty folders are not managed correctly.
In particular:

- if present in the source then they are not created in the destination
- renaming a folder in the source the destination structure is recreated leaving the previous folder empty

E.g.
Initial situation in source and destination is
a MainFolder containing a file 1.txt

The final situation in the source is a
RenamedFolder containing the 1.txt file

I expect everything replicated at the destination instead I find:
The RenamedFolder containing the 1.txt file (this is ok),
The NewFolder is empty (this is not ok)

Of course, from website, I can create and remove empty folders (v2 account) but I need to sync a lot of data so I cannot do it manually.

Any idea how to solve it? Isn’t this supported in v2 storage accounts?

Comment: What are your expectations? whether you need to sync the empty folder also?

Comment: I need a complete replication of the local folder in azure storage. It means I need to see empty folders and not find empty folders if a folder is renamed locally. No other applications is changing the azure storage data but I have a web app accessing read only

Comment: Refer this https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/1566

Comment: So it’s still unsolved and not supported by azcopy?

Comment: Yes, It is not supported in Azcopy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need a complete replication of the local folder in Azure storage. This means I need to see empty folders and not find empty folders if a folder is renamed locally.

- **`AzCopy sync`** does not support creating empty directories in Blob storage (Gen V2 storage account).
- `AzCopy sync "source" "destination" --delete-destination=true` does not delete empty directories.

Even when I tried, I encountered the same issue in my environment, and it is still not creating empty directories or folders and not deleting empty directories:

**Output:**

```
 azcopy sync "[Source]" "https://xxxx.blob.core.windows.net/test?sp=racwdlmeop&st=2024-01-22T06:48:30Z&se=2024-01-22T14:48:30Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=c&sig=xxxxx" --delete-destination=true
INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination don't have full folder support

Job xxxxxx494 has started
Log file is located at: C:\Users\v-vsettu\.azcopy\a02fec56-3b5b-b746-5b4f-7fec4cdf6494.log

100.0 %, 8 Done, 0 Failed, 0 Pending, 8 Total, 2-sec Throughput (Mb/s): 0

Job xxxx Summary
Files Scanned at Source: 8
Files Scanned at Destination: 4
Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.1672
Number of Copy Transfers for Files: 8
Number of Copy Transfers for Folder Properties: 0
Total Number Of Copy Transfers: 8
Number of Copy Transfers Completed: 8
Number of Copy Transfers Failed: 0
Number of Deletions at Destination: 4
Total Number of Bytes Transferred: 3282512
Total Number of Bytes Enumerated: 3282512
Final Job Status: Completed
```

**Portal:**
[image]

Currently, this feature is not supported in AzCopy. You can raise a new feature request through the **[GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues)** link.